# Using Javascript for Dropbox core api

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

I am not a js programmer. But for some reason, I have to write a js program to get the access token so that the program can use the dropbox core api.

what I have tried is the following:

```
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open("POST", "https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key=qxxxxxxxx&oauth_consumer_secret=axxxxxxxxx", false);
         xhr.send();
         console.log("status: " + xhr.statusText);
         console.log("response: " + xhr.responseText);
```

This is not work...I need help~

response: {"error": "Unauthorized"} this is the error message I received

Comment: A minor "word of warning". SO is really not meant to help nonprogrammers much.

Comment: The first potential issue I see is that AJAX requests are asynchronous. That is, after calling `send()`, the interpreter doesn't wait for the request to complete. Your logging statements don't print anything because the request is still waiting. That said I don't know from memory whether XHR defaults to synchronous or asynchronous mode, mostly because I tend to use jQuery to deal with AJAX.

Comment: response: {"error": "Unauthorized"} this is the error message I received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `request_token` has to be signed with OAuth. You should be passing an `Authorization` header that looks something like this (using a `PLAINTEXT` signature):

```
OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="<app key>", oauth_signature="<app secret>&"
```

But, before you go down this path, you should really use OAuth 2 instead. It's simpler than OAuth 1. The only reason I can see to use OAuth 1 is if you're app can't be hosted on HTTPS. (OAuth 2 requires an HTTPS redirect URI.)

And, before you build that all by hand, you should just use [dropbox-js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js). Then your code would be something like this:

```
var client = new Dropbox.Client({key: '<app secret>'});
client.authenticate();
```